# ckeditor 3.x dataProcessor get native dom element

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to attach an onclick event for a ckeditor "element" that matches my criteria using the dataProcessor htmlFilter.  The sdk documents a method $ that returns a native dom element of the internal "element".

> {Object} $ Since: 3.0 The native DOM object represented by this class
>   instance. var element = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( 'span' ); alert(
>   element.$.nodeType );  // "1"

What I want to accomplish is this:

I would like to show a custom popup window to for the user to enter special notes when a user clicks on a div in the document that has an attribute "data-notes".  The content entered by the user is then inserted in the innerHTML of that div.  I might have several sections in the document where "notes" can be inserted and a user might include a template in the current document that will also contain a "notes" or another section that should be clickable as well by additional htmlFilter rules.

```
 editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
                    {
                        elements :
                        {
                            div : function( element )
                            {
                                if (element.attributes.data-notes) {
                                  console.log(element) // exists..great
                                  console.log(element.$) // undefined!
                                  element.$.onclick = function() { ... }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataProcessor works neither on native DOM elements nor CKEditor elements. It works on simplified, synthetic elements, which are nothing more than a text representation of DOM (tag + attributes + inner content). So you can't follow this way.

A solution for you is something similar to the [placeholder plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/placeholder/plugin.js) ([demo](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7654/_samples/placeholder.html)). The difference is that your plugin will have a slightly different [getSelectedPlaceholder](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/placeholder/plugin.js#L132) implementation (as you're looking for div with a specific attribute), [onclick](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/placeholder/plugin.js#L58) (instead of doubleclick; I wouldn't change this though), no [createPlaceholder](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/placeholder/plugin.js#L103) and no [dataProcessor stuff](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/placeholder/plugin.js#L74-99).

Have a nice coding! ;)

Comment: Thank you..I've figured that much.  I ended up using editor.document.$.getElementsByClassName, binding the onclick event and replacing the elements innerHTML when closing my custom pop up.